# Using gradle project in both Eclipse and IDEA

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I have an Android project created in Android Studio. It works fine in Android Studio, IDEA and build machine.
Now we have several new developers who work in Eclipse and I can't set it up. Is it possible to convert gradle(android studio) project to Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Don't convert the build system, gradle is pretty nice. I'm pretty sure gradle can be integrated into eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to maintain the build separately in both Gradle and Eclipse; Eclipse can't use the Android Gradle builder natively. It's on our list of things to implement but we don't have a roadmap for it yet.

Things will go easiest if you use an Eclipse-like directory structure and adapt the Gradle build file to work with it. See [Maintaining directory structure during Android Studio import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782813/maintaining-directory-structure-during-android-studio-import/21783822#21783822) for advice.

Comment: What about *.aar files?

Comment: We have several lib projects builded as aar archives and gradle attach these archives to the project. How to attach them to eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support .aar, so you'll have to follow whatever instructions those libraries have for working in Eclipse, and treat them differently in both build systems.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`Eclipse Compatibility Mode`](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+in+Eclipse+Compatibility+Mode) in Android Studio and Idea.

Or

- Use Gradle and the new Build system in Eclipse: [Is there any way to integrate Eclipse with Gradle in Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project)