# Using Android Studio to work on an Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, android-studio

We have an eclipse project on svn, is there a way i could work on it with Android Studio while still preserving it in that state so i can commit it back to SVN?

The optimal solution would be if i could connect it to the svn over Android Studi and use the built in svn client. Is there any way to do any of this?

I know that there are other files that are created (gradle...) and that the directory structure is different but i mainly need access to the src dir, the res dir and android manifest and the ability to commit all of this back to svn (using an external svn client is also an option).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using gradle project in both Eclipse and IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854335/using-gradle-project-in-both-eclipse-and-idea)

Comment: "i mainly need access to the src dir, the res dir and android manifest and the ability to commit all of this back to svn (using an external svn client is also an option)." It is exactly what I need !! Any news in this direction since the Android Studio Beta was released @ScottBarta ?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has full support for SVN, so that should be no problem.

You can also get gradle/studio working with eclipses file structure. 
Have a look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide, and the Configuring the Structure section. You just need to point the src,res and manifest to the location in the current project.

The tricky part may be dependencies. If all your dependencies are jars, you will be fine. Otherwise if the dependencies are projects, you will need to convert those too.

Also, make sure you ignore all the intellij, and gradle files in svn.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easy to convert to android studio path format, and change path in eclipse. For correct moving use svn command svn move -m "commit message" "old_path/file.file" "new_path/file.file"