# Is it possible to use Android Studio AND Eclipse in a team

Tags: eclipse, jar, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio re-arranges the structure of projects imported from eclipse. I have just joined a team which is using Eclipse but I would like to use Android Studio and impact their current work practices as little as possible. Is there anyway it is possible for a team to use the 2 IDEs and share the same repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set up a Gradle build file for use by Android Studio, and maintain the Eclipse project files separately; there will be no automated way of keeping the two synchronized.

Gradle-based projects like to have a different directory structure than old-style Eclipse projects; you'll need to adapt the Gradle project to use Eclipse-style directories.

There's some advice on how to do that at [Maintaining directory structure during Android Studio import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782813/maintaining-directory-structure-during-android-studio-import/21783822#21783822) but the basic idea is to set up your build file like this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay Scott I will try this soon, quick question though do I need to export from Eclipse and then change the build.gradle to look like this? Or is it easier / more manageable to import the eclipse project itself? Thanks.

Comment: I would import the eclipse project itself. I know it's not really documented, but at the moment, Eclipse import from Android Studio is much more robust than Gradle export from Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was put off by importing directly into Android Studio because it makes a copy of the whole project and that would have made it kind of awkward to commit to our repo with my terrible knowledge of Git :D So luckily I managed to export the Eclipse gradle files without too much hassle at all actually so now I'm pretty happy.