# How do I import an eclipse project into Android Studio without creating a reorganized copy of the repo?

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I have an Android project currently developed in Eclipse. I would like to transition to Android Studio, without losing the ability to fall back on Eclipse.

When I import a "non android studio project", a copy of my repository is made, and my directory structure is reorganized to conform to the gradle style.

My question is, how can I import my repository in-place, without reorganizing the directory structure?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782813/maintaining-directory-structure-during-android-studio-import

Comment: This is probably a dupe, but the answer below provides more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set up your `build.gradle` file manually. Then, when you import into Android Studio, it will see the `build.gradle` file and use it, rather than go through the reorganization process.

Here is a starter `build.gradle` file you can drop into your Eclipse project directory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

The big things that you will want to adjust are:

- the `compileSdkVersion`, which should match the build target that you are using for Eclipse (see your `project.properties` file)
- the `buildToolsVersion`, which should reference a "Build-tools" that you have installed in the SDK Manager (where `"21.1.2"` is the currently-latest version)

The comments shown above are there because the file started with one exported from Eclipse, as if you are on the current ADT plugin, you can export a `build.gradle` file. However, that plugin has not been updated in quite some time, and I expect that the `build.gradle` file it would generate would be largely broken.

You may also wish to set up a basic Gradle wrapper, to smooth the import process. To do that, create a `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file off your Eclipse project root, with the following contents:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

The big thing here is the `distributionUrl`, which points to an official Gradle distribution, specifically the 2.2.1 that Android Studio 1.0 and Gradle for Android 1.0 like.

So, add those two files to your Eclipse project, and then Android Studio should import-in-place without any file reorganization.

You can see [a few hundred projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) set up this way.

Comment: Perfect. Is this basically the gradle file that Eclipse generates? Did you import (hundreds of times!) the projects as existing studio projects, or non-android studio projects (as suggested in the Android developer docs)?

Comment: @MM.: "Is this basically the gradle file that Eclipse generates?" -- with updated versions for the various bits (e.g., Gradle for Android plugin), yes. "Did you import (hundreds of times!) the projects as existing studio projects, or non-android studio projects" -- using the terminology of Android Studio 1.0.1, these would be "non-Android Studio projects".