# Exception in plugin android support.Moments Ago

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android project in eclipse . I want to move to android studio.i followed this link . 
[How do I import an eclipse project into Android Studio without creating a reorganized copy of the repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495316/how-do-i-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-without-creating-a-reorga)

I got the project imported in Studio , with the existing structure as it is. Now i wanted to add dependencies in the build.gradle file . 
My project has many folders containing jars. When i right click on any jar > add as library > It says "Exception in plugin android support . Moments Ago .Occured 10 times since the last clear . Unread . Disable"

How do i resolve it . Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From provided link there is one important line about dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

It says to **Gradle** that in folder `libs` are dependencies that are jar files.
Duplicate that line and change `libs` to the name of the folder where you have other **jar** files. If you have **aar** dependencies then you need to change filter `*.jar` to `*.jar,*.aar` to include them as well.

I would also really relayout project to the standard android (java) layout. It will save you a lot of time with third party gradle plugins and tons of examples to understand.

I would also invest some time in learning **Gradle** itself